# Fast Style Transfer tensorflow Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I follow this link to try machine learning - real time Fast Style Transfer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWlbFVtPiwo&ab_channel=CODEMENTAL.

However, in my python it shows GPU available:  False Does it matter?
Moreover, if I only want to hold the real time Fast Style Transfer no need the video and image one what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

GPU is recommended  in computation intensive deep learning problems and  you need both "Source" and "Style" image either in cloud or local storage to get a Fast Style transfer image.Attaching [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_arbitrary_image_stylization) for your reference.